# Unknown bridge gets recreated after reboot on Ubuntu 15.04@VMWare

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vmware, bridge, ifconfig

I am running Ubuntu 15.04 on VMWare. For the last couple of days I have the issue that I have a "magic" network bridge:

[image: Magic bridge]

I never created this bridge and therefore I tried to delete it with the following commands:

```
# ip link set br-97843df62fc9 down
# brctl delbr br-97843df62fc9
```

That works fine until I've rebooted my VM... After the reboot the bridge was back..
I guess some program or service is adding the bridge on startup. Recently I have installed a Jetty plugin for IntelliJ for testing and a local Cassandra installation (I already uninstalled Cassandra which didn't fix my issue)

Does somebody know how I can permanently delete this bridge?

Comment: Installed Docker recently?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue after following this guide [1] and then wanting to get rid of the bridge again.

It turned out that the mere fact that `br0` was mentioned in `hostapd.conf` caused it to show up again, even after deleting it in every way I could think of. Hope that helps someone else.. :)

```
interface=wlan0
bridge=br0 <- delete!
#driver=nl80211
ssid=NameOfNetwork
hw_mode=g
channel=7
```

[1] https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md